# cannot resolve symbol 'menu'?

Tags: android, menu, android-menu

I have tried to clean up, rebuild and debug my code. I am making a simple quiz (GEO Quiz). I have a menu folder in my resources but there is nothing in it, but I still can get the error to go away. This is my first app.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;


    public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
        private Button tButton;
        private Button fButton;

        //private Question[] questions= new Question[5];
        //private int qNum =0;


      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }
      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
          return true;
      }


       }
```

[image: Screenshot of error problem]

My layout and string.xml are correct thus far. Whenever i type in `R.` into the `onCreateOptionsMenu` class. There is no list or prompt that says `menu` on it.

[image: This is how my project looks]

Comment: activity_main isn't the menu file so you have to create a menu file in menu res folder and then inflate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You should have menu.xml in menu folder*

if not, add the **menu.xml** file inside **/res/menu/** folder, this is an example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="75"
    android:title="my menu Item!"
    app:showAsAction="never"/></menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your menu resource folder does not have any xml file. the menu file should be on the menu resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for my mac was to install MAMP. XAMPP did not work and locating files was confusing.

When entering commands in terminal all files had protection and contraints I could not do anything.

So MAMP is the best bet to solve this question. Make sure to use the php file in CLI interpeter.